# Is there a way to change Thunderbird's file permissions when saving attachments?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 3.x on Ubuntu (Linux). When I save an attachment to my computer, the file gets saved with only the owner (me) having read/write permissions. In other words, the file gets saved as `-rw-------`.

Frequently, I want my group to have permission, or to give read permission to everyone. Is there a way to do change Thunderbird's default file permissions so I don't have to do this manually every time?

Comment: Its a bug and it is supposed to be fixed in 3.3: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=533976